# `table` option in report documentclass

Tags: document-classes

I came across a LaTeX template for a report with the following documentclass options:

```latex
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    twoside, 
    table,
    openright,
    openany
]{report}
```

What is the `table` parameter doing?

Comment: A good candidate for making use of the global option `table` would be the `xcolor` package. Does the `xcolor` package get loaded in the preamble?

Comment: Yes, the `xcolor` package is being loaded in the preamble!

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hunch. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Any such options are passed to all packages, if no package uses it you get an `unused global option` warning, but it is not an error.